# What can cause a `SCRIPT5007: Object expected` with Edge 17 in this situation?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have the following in a function, as part of a large webapp:

```
if (! win) {
  return null;
}
if (! ("document" in win)) {
  return null;
}
doc = win.document;
```

When this code runs in Edge 17, I get the following error on the console:

```
SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Object expected
```

The error points to the line with `doc = win.document`. My question is: how is this possible? And if caused by a bug in Edge, how can I get around this?

I should also note that the issue doesn't happen with Chrome, Firefox, or IE11. I can reproduce the error consistently. If I open the Dev Tools (aka F12 Tools) before reproducing the issue, the problem doesn't happen, which means that I can't just put a breakpoint in the relevant location.

Comment: is your edge in compatibility mode?

Comment: @DanielA.White Good question, and I'm trying to check in the Emulation tab where I think it used to be, but I don't see the document mode mentioned there. See: https://i.imgur.com/NOM6cGP.png. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use full 'window.document'.

Also try to check and confirm that object and variables are declared before you assign the value to it.

Try to refer example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Hello, World!</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var doc = window.document;
   console.log(doc.title); // Hello, World!
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can try to make a test with Edge and check whether it is working on your side or not.

Regards

Deepak